# Pandas: df.set_value() method erases / resets column names of MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing an application that makes use of pandas (version 0.10.1) to store the underlying data model as a (3-level) MultiIndex'ed DataFrame. The model is a line spectrum, and the top level of the index is the atomic transition.

A simple dataframe could look like this:

```
                               Pos     Sigma       Ampl  Line center Identifier
H-alpha-6697.6 30-30 Comp2  -3.600  0.774000  33.058000       6699.5          b
                     Comp3   3.538  2.153000  28.054000       6699.5          c
                     Contin    NaN       NaN   0.000000          NaN        NaN
                     Comp4   1.384  0.921000  37.504000       6699.5          d
                     Comp1  -2.124  1.977000  69.166000       6699.5          a
               31-31 Comp2  -3.292  0.884603  49.813423       6699.5          b
                     Comp3   3.600  2.299000  19.999000       6699.5          c
                     Contin    NaN       NaN   0.000000          NaN        NaN
                     Comp4   1.692  1.009000  22.222000       6699.5          d
                     Comp1  -1.262  2.534000  68.002000       6699.5          a
```

At some point, I need to be able to create a different transition, e.g. H-beta, using H-alpha as a template. I would ideally do this by something like `df.ix['H-beta-wavelength'] = df.ix['H-alpha-6697.6']`, but this is not possible to do. So instead, I tried following this example: [Prepend a level to a pandas MultiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744068/prepend-a-level-to-a-pandas-multiindex)

However, the example above requires the `.names` of the multiindex levels to be set in order to reorder them. And the `names` attribute is set when initializing the dataframe, but during the building of it, I rely quite extensibly on the set_values() method, and doing this destroys the `names` attribute - or rather sets them to `[None, None, None]`.

Example:

```
In [68]: df
Out[68]: 
                                  Pos  Sigma     Ampl  Line center Identifier
Transition     Rows  Component                                               
Center: 6699.5 26-26 Comp2     -3.846  0.657  15.2740       6699.5          b
                     Comp3      2.924  1.449  31.3930       6699.5          c
                     Contin       NaN    NaN   0.0000          NaN        NaN
                     Comp4      8.030  1.009   7.0831       6699.5          d
                     Comp1     -1.816  2.153  50.2750       6699.5          a

In [69]: df.set_value(('Center: 5044.3', '26-26', 'Comp1'), 'Sigma', 2.457)
Out[69]: 
                               Pos  Sigma     Ampl  Line center Identifier
Center: 6699.5 26-26 Comp2  -3.846  0.657  15.2740       6699.5          b
                     Comp3   2.924  1.449  31.3930       6699.5          c
                     Contin    NaN    NaN   0.0000          NaN        NaN
                     Comp4   8.030  1.009   7.0831       6699.5          d
                     Comp1  -1.816  2.153  50.2750       6699.5          a
Center: 5044.3 26-26 Comp1     NaN  2.457      NaN          NaN        NaN
```

Of course, this makes it quite hard to use the names for reordering the levels of the multiindex. Is there a way to avoid this, short of brute-force setting the names after each time I've run `set_values()`?

### EDIT: simpler, reproducible example.

Here is an iPython session recreating the `index.names` problem with a somewhat simpler example. It also shows that it is possibly a bug that goes beyond `index.names`, as it seems to change the `index.lexsort_depth` from 3 to 0. Missing numbers in the prompt are just unnecessary views of the dataframe.
I believe that one must choose secondary and/or tertiary indices that already exist like I have done below in order to reproduce it.

```
In [4]: idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
            [['Hans']*4 + ['Grethe']*4, ['1', '1', '2', '2']*2, ['a', 'b']*4], 
            names=['Name', 'Number', 'Letter'])

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(
            random.random((8, 3)), 
            columns=['one', 'two','three'], 
            index=idx)


In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
                           one       two     three
Name   Number Letter                              
Hans   1      a       0.803566  0.434574  0.805976
              b       0.655322  0.208469  0.989559
       2      a       0.893952  0.380358  0.173764
              b       0.822446  0.673894  0.676573
Grethe 1      a       0.202641  0.387263  0.405296
              b       0.646733  0.086953  0.882114
       2      a       0.358458  0.147107  0.769586
              b       0.183782  0.477863  0.601098

# To rule out another possible source of problems:
In [9]: df.unstack().drop(('Grethe', '1')).stack()
Out[9]: 
                           one       two     three
Name   Number Letter                              
Grethe 2      a       0.358458  0.147107  0.769586
              b       0.183782  0.477863  0.601098
Hans   1      a       0.803566  0.434574  0.805976
              b       0.655322  0.208469  0.989559
       2      a       0.893952  0.380358  0.173764
              b       0.822446  0.673894  0.676573

In [10]: df.set_value(('Frans', '2', 'b'), 'one', 23.)
Out[10]: 
                  one       two     three
Hans   1 a   0.803566  0.434574  0.805976
         b   0.655322  0.208469  0.989559
       2 a   0.893952  0.380358  0.173764
         b   0.822446  0.673894  0.676573
Grethe 1 a   0.202641  0.387263  0.405296
         b   0.646733  0.086953  0.882114
       2 a   0.358458  0.147107  0.769586
         b   0.183782  0.477863  0.601098
Frans  2 b  23.000000       NaN       NaN

In [11]: df = df.sortlevel(level='Name')

In [13]: df.index.lexsort_depth
Out[13]: 3

In [14]: df.set_value(('Frans', '2', 'b'), 'one', 23.).index.lexsort_depth
Out[14]: 0
```

Comment: can u add pandas version?

Comment: Pandas version is 0.10.1. Added to the question.

Comment: I realize that I can reorder the levels by integer index instead of by name, and if that is the only solution, I'll write this as the answer.
However, it seems like broken or at least unintentional behavior, and I hope there is another answer out there, so I'll wait a bit.

Comment: Strangely, when trying a simpler example (of both a single index and multiindex I can't recreate this on 0.10.1 - the names seem to propogate)...

Comment: Andy, Maybe that is because of what Jeff mentions about sortedness of the index? If you have performed no operations on it that messes up its sortedness, that would apparently not raise the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to Andy Hayden, this is a `names` bug in pandas. 
Hopefully a fix will come soon.

Until then, I believe the best way to do this is to do the following:

```
tmp = df.ix['ExistingTransition'].copy()
tmp['Transition'] = 'NewTransition'
tmp = tmp.set_index('Transition', append=True)
tmp.index = tmp.index.reorder_levels([2, 0, 1])
# ...Do whatever else needs to be done to this before applying as template...
df = df.append(tmp)
```

...That, or making sure thet the `names` attribute is recreated after each run of `set_values()`, and then just going by the example linked in the question.

Comment: his frame is not sorted, see above (it should work non the less so it is 'sort'a bug)

Comment: I have marked this as the correct answer. It is true that the DataFrame needs to be sorted, but the problem persists even when doing so.
The bug has not been squashed in Pandas 0.11

Answer (score 1):

Your index needs to be sorted! See docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#the-need-for-sortedness and these recipes may help http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/cookbook.html
This is 0.10.1 as well

Heres a sorted frame

```
In [26]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], [1, 2, 1, 2]],
              names=['first', 'second'])

In [27]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(index)), index=index,columns=['A'])

In [7]: df.index.lexsort_depth
Out[7]: 2

In [28]: df.set_value(('a',1),'A',1)
Out[28]: 
                     A
first second          
a     1       1.000000
      2       0.136456
b     1       0.712612
      2       0.818473
```

And if I sort by the 2nd level (so its unsorted)

```
In [29]: df2 = df.sortlevel(level='second')

# this is not sorted! (well it is, just not lexsorted)
In [10]: df2.index.lexsort_depth
Out[10]: 0

In [30]: df2.set_value(('b','1'),'A',2)
Out[30]: 
            A
a 1  1.000000
b 1  0.712612
a 2  0.136456
b 2  0.818473
  1  2.000000
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. If my index is sorted, will that prevent the `names` list from being reset? It doesn't seem like that in your example, it looks to me like your `names` has gone after `set_value()` is run, too?

Comment: in the 2nd case, just to show you what an unsorted index does! the first case is what you want, try ``df.sortlevel(level='first',inplace=True)``, try printing the sort depth, I'll update my answer

Comment: Ah, thank you, now I see it. I'm not sure I understand how I should do it in practice, though. My dataframe is initialized with a "dummy" row that is deleted as soon as any actual data is inserted - which for the first part is done exclusively by `set_value()`. At which points should I make sure the index is sorted? And do I need to do this every time I've run `set_value()` (that seems unnecessarily laborious...)?

Comment: So, I just tested on a very simple dataframe with a well-sorted index. Using the dataframe from the second example in my question, I try running `set_values()` with a realistic set of parameters and get this:

`B.set_value(('Foo', '26-26', 'Comp1'), 'Pos', 2.435).index.names` gives `[None, None, None]`, and 
`B.set_value(('Foo', '26-26', 'Comp1'), 'Pos', 2.435).index.lexsort_depth` gives `2`

So it looks like the `lexsort_depth` is preserved, but the `names` still destroyed.

Comment: if your set_value operation increases the size of the frame it returns a new object; it is possible there is a bug lurking. can u give me a better idea of why u r thing to do, maybe I can give u r a better answer. if u r setting a lot of values like this it will be somewhat inefficient. oftentimes it's better to create a new frame and perform a join/ concat operation

Comment: It is an interactive interface to do fitting-by-eye and provide initial guesses to a fitting package. This means the dataframes are relatively small, and that the user interaction by far is the speed bottleneck. The dataframe is filled by ~5 `set_value()` operations at a time after a user clicks "OK". So I doubt there'd be much efficiency to be gained by changing the mode of operation. The `set_value()` operation is great because it doesn't need to know what's already in the dataframe, it just changes a value if the indices already exist and adds it if not, which is exactly what I need.

Comment: ...But could you possibly elaborate on the index sorting thing that I asked about above? Like, when in such a case should a sorting be done, and would it only need to be the top level?

Comment: ...I am thinking doing some kind of merge of our answers would provide the best one. It is good to know that sorting is necessary, but it doesnøt seem to solve the problem in this particular case...

Comment: strictly speaking sortness in a multi-index is ALWAYS necessary for indexing, so there for set_value requires it, that said, there are certainly conditions where it doesn't matter, and there are probably bugs lurking, best to sort until this is 'sorted' out...there is an issue open pointing to this question, so will get addressed

Comment: Should I apply the `df.sortlevel(level='Transition')` after each `df.set_value()` call?

Comment: Btw @Jeff, I think the different outcomes of the two examples in your answer is due to the fact that the first sets a new value of an existing entry, the second expands the index with a new row.
I don't think it's the sorting part that does it, as you can see in the edit of my question.