# Add multi-index to pandas dataframe and keep current index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am trying to merge time-course data from different participants. I am iteratively extracting a dataframe per participant and concatenating them at the end of the loop. Before I concatenate, I would like to add the ID of my participants to an additional index.

This seems REALLY straightforward, but I was unable to find anything on this issue :(

I would like to turn this

```
    col
0     1
1   1.1
2   NaN
```

Into:

```
          col
ID    0     1
      1   1.1
      2   NaN
```

I know I could make a new index like:

```
multindex = [np.array(ID*len(data)),np.array(np.arange(len(data)))]
```

But that's inelegant without end, and - seeing as I am measuring with high frequency over half an hour - would even get kind of slow :/

**I would like to mention that I have recently found my question to be a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744068/prepend-a-level-to-a-pandas-multiindex). However mine apparently has more upvotes and better answers. “Prepend” apparently doesn't seem to draw as many hits.**

Comment: It might be better to just add the ID as a column, then add to index when you concat ?

Comment: Andy, that is indeed the answer given in the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744068/prepend-a-level-to-a-pandas-multiindex) as well. Seems to me like a better answer than the one accepted here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe you can use `keys` argument of `concat`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 2))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 2))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 2))

print pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], keys=["A", "B", "C"])
```

output:

```
            0         1
A 0  0.863774  0.794880
  1  0.578503  0.418619
  2  0.215317  0.146167
B 0  0.655829  0.116917
  1  0.862316  0.812847
  2  0.500126  0.689218
  3  0.653439  0.270427
C 0  0.825213  0.882963
  1  0.579436  0.332047
  2  0.456948  0.718893
  3  0.795074  0.826773
  4  0.049676  0.697471
```

If you want to append other dataframes later:

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6, 2))
pd.concat([df, pd.concat([df4], keys=["D"])])
```

Comment: Though the keys can be useful at times, I don't think this actually answers the question. This way another concat cannot be made afterwards, which the question seemed to imply would be necessary. So, e.g. I don't see how you could easily append `df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2))` with a new key `"D"` after having done the above. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744068/prepend-a-level-to-a-pandas-multiindex) seems more suited to this purpose.