# Setting new MultiIndex into pandas DataFrame columns gives ValueError: all arrays must be same length

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following DataFrame, called 'pdf':

```
           1   2   3    4    5    6    7  9
Q45a_1   247  95  62  187  162  216  536  0
Q45a_2   134  48  34   90   79   84  232  0
Q45a_3    59  24  14   40   28   47  112  0
Q45a_4    50  24  10   25   21   30   98  0
Q45a_5    41  27  16   15   17   26   52  0
Q45a_6    31  15   8   15   23   22   50  0
Q45a_7    48  23   9   65   46   52  119  0
Q45a_8   198  66  43  154  131  155  422  0
Q45a_9   227  81  55  164  155  177  489  0
Q45a_10  173  77  49  120  103  162  375  0
Q45a_11   81  42  22   45   45   68  148  0
Q45a_98   18  22   8   11    9   16   64  0
Q45a_99   25  17   4    9    9   13   47  0
```

I am trying to redefine/set the columns using this MultiIndex:

```
Question         Values
bpcn             1     
                 2     
                 3     
                 4     
                 5     
                 6     
                 7     
                 9
```

By using this code:

```
pdf.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(['bpcn', pdf.columns], names=['Question','Values'])
```

Although this line doesn't itself produce an error, the DataFrame is thereafter broken and when referenced returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.5.0.201405201709\pysrc\pydevd_comm.py", line 915, in doIt
    result = pydevd_vars.evaluateExpression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
  File "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.5.0.201405201709\pysrc\pydevd_vars.py", line 482, in evaluateExpression
    sys.stdout.write('%s\n' % (result,))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 34, in __str__
    return self.__bytes__()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 46, in __bytes__
    return self.__unicode__().encode(encoding, 'replace')
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 464, in __unicode__
    line_width=width, show_dimensions=show_dimensions)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1299, in to_string
    formatter.to_string()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 441, in to_string
    strcols = self._to_str_columns()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 363, in _to_str_columns
    for i, c in enumerate(frame):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 647, in __iter__
    return iter(self._info_axis)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 666, in __iter__
    return iter(self.values)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 2486, in values
    self._tuples = lib.fast_zip(values)
  File "lib.pyx", line 487, in pandas.lib.fast_zip (pandas\lib.c:9827)
ValueError: all arrays must be same length
```

The confusing thing about this is that I can redefine/set the index using the same MultiIndex approach without a problem, such as:

```
pdf.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(['Q45a', pdf.index], names=['Question','Values'])
```

Which gives me:

```
                    1   2   3    4    5    6    7  9
Question Values                                     
Q45a     Q45a_1   247  95  62  187  162  216  536  0
         Q45a_2   134  48  34   90   79   84  232  0
         Q45a_3    59  24  14   40   28   47  112  0
         Q45a_4    50  24  10   25   21   30   98  0
         Q45a_5    41  27  16   15   17   26   52  0
         Q45a_6    31  15   8   15   23   22   50  0
         Q45a_7    48  23   9   65   46   52  119  0
         Q45a_8   198  66  43  154  131  155  422  0
         Q45a_9   227  81  55  164  155  177  489  0
         Q45a_10  173  77  49  120  103  162  375  0
         Q45a_11   81  42  22   45   45   68  148  0
         Q45a_98   18  22   8   11    9   16   64  0
         Q45a_99   25  17   4    9    9   13   47  0
```

I must be missing something, but why does the same approach not work for both the DataFrame index and columns?

***EDIT***:

I think this must be a bug with MultiIndex.from_product() because the long version, using MultiIndex.from_tuples() works:

```
pdf.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(['Q45a', pdf.index], names=['Question','Values'])
pdf.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('bpcn', 1), ('bpcn', 2), ('bpcn', 3), ('bpcn', 4), ('bpcn', 5), ('bpcn', 6), ('bpcn', 7), ('bpcn', 9)], names=('Question', 'Values'))
```

Gives what I wanted to begin with:

```
Question          bpcn                               
Values               1   2   3    4    5    6    7  9
Question Values                                      
Q45a     Q45a_1    247  95  62  187  162  216  536  0
         Q45a_2    134  48  34   90   79   84  232  0
         Q45a_3     59  24  14   40   28   47  112  0
         Q45a_4     50  24  10   25   21   30   98  0
         Q45a_5     41  27  16   15   17   26   52  0
         Q45a_6     31  15   8   15   23   22   50  0
         Q45a_7     48  23   9   65   46   52  119  0
         Q45a_8    198  66  43  154  131  155  422  0
         Q45a_9    227  81  55  164  155  177  489  0
         Q45a_10   173  77  49  120  103  162  375  0
         Q45a_11    81  42  22   45   45   68  148  0
         Q45a_98    18  22   8   11    9   16   64  0
         Q45a_99    25  17   4    9    9   13   47  0
```

***EDIT 2***

Apologies for the edits, but I thought I should confirm that even the above 'working' example is still broken (if you try to access pdf.T you will get the same error as above). Fairly certain from_product() is the problem.

Also, I thought I should provide my work-around for this to avoid the problem. I am using instead from_tuples() in this form:

```
pdf.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Q45a', val) for val in pdf.index], names=('Question', 'Values'))
pdf.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('bpcn', val) for val in pdf.columns], names=('Question', 'Values'))
```

Comment: ``MultiIndex.from_product()`` takes a list-of-lists, a string is considered a list, so it gets expanded into its characters. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, looks like I overcomplicated it just a tad. Appreciate the kind bump to RTFM.

Comment: ha! I suspect you actually want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744068/prepend-a-level-to-a-pandas-multiindex

Comment: 'prepend' .. obviously I don't use that word nearly enough. That is exactly what I want. :)

Comment: Here's some more recipes: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/cookbook.html#multiindexing