# pandas, how to add columns to a multiindex column DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

This is my original DataFrame (with multiindex column):

```
In [72]:df
Out[72]: 
          a                   b          
          x         y         x         y
0  1.545293 -0.459270  0.899254 -1.010453
1  0.458760  0.275400 -0.190951  0.169195
2 -0.941817  1.109823  0.077953 -0.247074
3  1.790101 -1.643470  0.979625 -1.704657
4 -2.044814 -0.243726 -0.039724  0.600066
```

and I have another DataFrame:

```
In [77]:df2
Out[77]: 
          x         y
0 -1.085869 -0.952949
1  0.601585  0.570050
2  0.328601  0.802610
3 -0.415952 -0.090088
4  0.757545 -0.736933
```

how can I add `df2`'s columns to `df` to get a new DataFrame like this:

```
In [83]:df3
Out[83]: 
          a                   b                   c          
          x         y         x         y         x         y
0  1.545293 -0.459270  0.899254 -1.010453 -1.085869 -0.952949
1  0.458760  0.275400 -0.190951  0.169195  0.601585  0.570050
2 -0.941817  1.109823  0.077953 -0.247074  0.328601  0.802610
3  1.790101 -1.643470  0.979625 -1.704657 -0.415952 -0.090088
4 -2.044814 -0.243726 -0.039724  0.600066  0.757545 -0.736933
```

My current approach is to use a for loop:

```
for col in df2.columns:
    df['c', col] = df2[col]
```

is there any method to avoid the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try `pd.concat`:

```
pieces = {'a' : df1['a'],
          'b' : df1['b'],
          'c' : df2}
df3 = pd.concat(pieces, axis=1)
```

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to do the above *without* deconstructing the inner columns of `df1`? Seems like there must be something.

Comment: You could use answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744068/prepend-a-level-to-a-pandas-multiindex to prepend a level to your other `df`, then use `pd.concat` as demonstrated in this answer

Answer (score 1):

I discovered another way to do this in the **general case** (running Python 3.6), without having to explicitly deconstruct the `DataFrame`. You can use `pd.concat` with the dictionary argument,

```
df3 = pd.concat({**df1, **{('c',nm):val for nm,val in df2.items()})
```

`**` expansion on `DataFrame` objects seems to return a dictionary of **Series** objects with "names" equal to the column name string/value, or if the columns are **MultiIndexed**, the tuple containing the hieararchy of column string/values. Then, when read back into `pd.concat` as a dictionary, `Pandas` re-constructs the MultiIndexed columns from the tuples.

Note this is much less efficient than the direct assignment you were doing! Since it has to deconstruct each column and MultiIndex of the dataframe, then re-combine.

Answer (score 0):

I think stacking is the best solution here:

```
# First stack df and df2
df, df2 = df.stack(), df2.stack()

# Then add df2 to df as a column
df2['c'] = df2

# Now unstack
df2 = df2.unstack()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add a column level ("c") to `df2`. Then, concatenate both dataframes.

```
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(["c"], df.columns])
df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```