# python3.5/pandas - rolling mean by week and hour

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to figure out how to use the rolling mean that takes into consideration the day and hour before computing the statistic.

File looks something like this:

```
 date       hour    price
 1/1/2016    1        a
 1/1/2016    2        b
    .        .        .
    .        .        .
 1/8/2016    1        c
 1/8/2016    2        d
    .        .        .
    .        .        .
 1/15/2016   1        e
 1/15/2016   2        f
```

while the output column should be something like this.

```
 date       hour    price    ma
 1/1/2016    1        a
 1/1/2016    2        b
    .        .        .
    .        .        .
 1/8/2016    1        c
 1/8/2016    2        d
    .        .        .
    .        .        .
 1/15/2016   1        e    mean(a,c)
 1/15/2016   2        f    mean(b,d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this with a grain of salt as I don't really know what I'm doing, but I think I had this problem myself and here was the best solution I could figure out. I'm sure there is a built-in function for it, but...

```
#assumes index contains date info (mine had Hour, dow, and a date field)
# and assumes ordered by datetime timestampe

df_subset_for_rolling = df['Values to Avg'].groupby(level=['Hour','day_of_week','Timestamp Date']).mean().fillna(0)

list_of_unique_dow = df_subset_for_rolling.index.get_level_values('Hour').unique().tolist()
list_of_unique_hour = df_subset_for_rolling.index.get_level_values('day_of_week').unique().tolist()

comb_dow_hour = [(d,h) for d in list_of_unique_dow for h in list_of_unique_hour]

rolling_avg_df = pd.DataFrame()
for h_d_tuple in comb_dow_hour:
    df_append = df_subset_for_rolling.loc[h_d_tuple,:].rolling(4,min_periods=3).mean()
    df_append = pd.concat([df_append],keys=[h_d_tuple[0]],names=['Hour'])
    df_append = pd.concat([df_append],keys=[h_d_tuple[1]],names=['day_of_week'])
    rolling_avg_df = rolling_avg_df.append(df_append,ignore_index=False)

df = df.join(rolling_avg_df)
```

Basically I just pulled each subset and then did a rolling cumulative avg, added that to a separate df, and then combined that back in to the original.

References: [Prepend a level to a pandas MultiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744068/prepend-a-level-to-a-pandas-multiindex) for adding back the index values

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear what you want but here are the assumption I made...

You want the mean by hour of all days before a certain date. This code does that...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# build a sample table
np.random.seed(1)
values = np.random.choice(range(1, 11), 25)
dates = np.random.choice(pd.date_range(datetime.date(2016, 1, 1), datetime.date(2016, 1, 4)), 25)
hours = np.random.choice(range(4), 25)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates, 'hour': hours, 'value': values})
```

df looks like this...

```
        date  hour  value
0 2016-01-03     1      6
1 2016-01-01     2      9
2 2016-01-03     2     10
3 2016-01-02     0      6
4 2016-01-03     3      1
5 2016-01-01     3      1
6 2016-01-04     1      2
7 2016-01-01     1      8
8 2016-01-03     3      7
9 2016-01-01     2     10
```

Now for the transformation you want...

```
df.sort_values(['date', 'hour'], inplace=True)
groups = df.groupby(['hour'])

# calculate the rolling mean and sub out the current day's value then...
#     divide by count of previous observations (works because cumcount is base 0)
df['rolling_mean'] = (groups.transform(np.cumsum)['value'] - df.value) / (groups.cumcount())

# just to show result
df.sort_values(['hour', 'date'])
```

result is...

```
        date  hour  value  rolling_mean
3 2016-01-02     0      6           NaN
7 2016-01-01     1      8           NaN
0 2016-01-03     1      6           8.0
6 2016-01-04     1      2           7.0
1 2016-01-01     2      9           NaN
9 2016-01-01     2     10           9.0
2 2016-01-03     2     10           9.5
5 2016-01-01     3      1           NaN
4 2016-01-03     3      1           1.0
8 2016-01-03     3      7           1.0
```

Up to you to do what you want with the NaNs...