# mapping a multi-index to existing pandas dataframe columns using separate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have an existing data frame in the following format (let's call it `df`):

```
               A     B     C     D
0              1     2     1     4
1              3     0     2     2
2              1     5     3     1
```

The column names were extracted from a spreadsheet that has the following form (let's call it `cat_df`):

```
                      current category
broader category
X                     A
Y                     B
Y                     C
Z                     D
```

First I'd like to prepend a higher level index to make `df` look like so:

```
               X     Y           Z
               A     B     C     D
0              1     2     1     4
1              3     0     2     2
2              1     5     3     1
```

Lastly i'd like to 'roll-up' the data into the meta-index by summing over subindices, to generate a new dataframe like so:

```
               X     Y     Z
0              1     3     4
1              3     2     2
2              1     8     1
```

Using `concat` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744068/prepend-a-level-to-a-pandas-multiindex) has gotten me close, but it seems like it'd be a very manual process picking out each subset. My true dataset is has a more complex mapping, so I'd like to refer to it directly as I build my meta-index. I think once I get the meta-index settled, a simple `groupby` should get me to the summation, but I'm still stuck on the first step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d = dict(zip(cat_df['current category'], cat_df.index))

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns.map(d.get), df.columns])
df.set_axis(cols, axis=1, inplace=False)

   X  Y     Z
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  1  4
1  3  0  2  2
2  1  5  3  1
```

---

```
df_new = df.set_axis(cols, axis=1, inplace=False)
df_new.groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum()

   X  Y  Z
0  1  3  4
1  3  2  2
2  1  8  1
```

Comment: This one worked great for me and was the most understandable. However, I had to make one modification as I'm using an older version of Pandas, `0.20.3`. I replaced the `set_axis()` line with `df.set_axis(1,cols)` (with the caveat that it changes the dataframe in place) as the syntax changed in version `0.22`.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can do it like this.

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cat_df.reset_index()[['broader category','current category']].apply(tuple, axis=1).tolist())
```

print(df)

Output:

```
   X  Y     Z
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  1  4
1  3  0  2  2
2  1  5  3  1
```

Sum level:

```
df.sum(level=0, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   X  Y  Z
0  1  3  4
1  3  2  2
2  1  8  1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can using `set_index` for creating the idx, then assign to your df

```
idx=df1.set_index('category',append=True).index

df.columns=idx

df
Out[1170]:
current   X  Y     Z
category  A  B  C  D
0         1  2  1  4
1         3  0  2  2
2         1  5  3  1

df.sum(axis=1,level=0)
Out[1171]: 
current  X  Y  Z
0        1  3  4
1        3  2  2
2        1  8  1
```