# Concatenating Index to MultiIndex in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have `pandas` `MultiIndex` object like so:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> arrays = [[1, 1, 2, 2], ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue']]
>>> multi = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('number', 'color'))
>>> print(multi)

MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2], ['blue', 'red']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0]],
           names=['number', 'color'])
```

I want to append a third index column from another source.

```
>>> idx = pd.Index(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b'], name='letter')
```

The final result should be a `MultiIndex` containing all three columns:

```
>>> pd.MagicFunctionICanNotFind(multi, idx)

MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2], ['blue', 'red'], ['a', 'b']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]],
           names=['number', 'color', 'letter'])
```

When I tried using the [`MultiIndex.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.append.html) function, it concatenated my new index values to the bottom of my index object instead of as a new level.  I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744068/prepend-a-level-to-a-pandas-multiindex) that wanted to do something similar, however that was working with a data frame, and here for long complicated reasons beyond the scope of this question, I am working with index objects.  Everything I have been trying using the underlying `values` of the two index objects has been getting rather complicated to the point that it doesn't seem to be the best path forward.  This has to be something that happens relatively frequently in the pandas codebase, is there an elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mock DataFrame and use `set_index`:

```
pd.DataFrame(index=multi).set_index(idx, append=True).index
```

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2], ['blue', 'red'], ['a', 'b']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]],
           names=['number', 'color', 'letter'])
```