# Convert MultiIndex to column suffixes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have this single `pd.DataFrame`

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['X', 'Y'], ['L', 'R']]), 
             data=[[1, 5, 2, 6],
                   [3, 7, 4, 8]])
```

which produces

```
    X       Y
    L   R   L   R
-----------------
0   1   5   2   6
1   3   7   4   8
```

I would like to add the upper index as a suffix to the column names, such that I produce something like this:

```
    L_X  R_X  L_Y  R_Y
----------------------
0   1    5    2    6
1   3    7    4    8
```

It is the inverse problem of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125606/convert-column-suffixes-from-pandas-join-into-a-multiindex), which is why I chose the exact same table.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
df.columns=[col[1] + "_" + col[0] for col in df.columns]
df
```

```
    L_X     R_X     L_Y     R_Y
0     1       5       2       6
1     3       7       4       8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` for this

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f"{x[1]}_{x[0]}")
```

```
   L_X  R_X  L_Y  R_Y
0    1    5    2    6
1    3    7    4    8
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`to_flat_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_flat_index.html) along with [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.swaplevel.html) and then just do a simple join.

```
df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel().to_flat_index().map("_".join)
```