# pd.Series assignment with pd.IndexSlice results in NaN values despite matching indices

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multi index series as below.

```
> data = [['a', 'X', 'u', 1], ['a', 'X', 'v', 2], ['b', 'Y', 'u', 4], ['a', 'Z', 'u', 20]]
> s = pd.DataFrame(data, columns='one two three four'.split()).set_index('one two three'.split()).four
> s
one  two  three
a    X    u         1
          v         2
b    Y    u         4
a    Z    u        20
Name: four, dtype: int64
```

Then a second series with only `one` and `three` as indices:

```
>>> data2 = [['a', 'u', 3], ['a', 'v', -3]]
>>> s2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns='one three four'.split()).set_index('one three'.split()).four
>>> s2
one  three
a    u        3
     v       -3
Name: four, dtype: int64
```

So, as far as I can see, `s2` and `s.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'X', :]]` are indexed identically.

As such I would expect to be able to do:

```
>>> s.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'X', :]] = s2
```

and yet doing so results in `NaN` values:

```
>>> s
one  two  three
a    X    u         NaN
          v         NaN
b    Y    u         4.0
a    Z    u        20.0
Name: four, dtype: float64
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why did commenter delete the s2.values comment?

Comment: @ScottBoston index alignment.

Comment: @QuangHoang True... true.

Comment: index alignment can be resolved by `sort_index` however. but I guess that's not the point of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pandas` MultiIndexes are sometimes a bit buggy, and this feels like one of those circumstances. If you modify `s2.index` to match `s.index`, the assignment works:

```
In [155]: s2.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a'], ['X'], ['u', 'v']], names=['one', 'two', 'three'])

In [156]: s2
Out[156]:
one  two  three
a    X    u        3
          v       -3
Name: four, dtype: int64

In [157]: s
Out[157]:
one  two  three
a    X    u         1
          v         2
b    Y    u         4
a    Z    u        20
Name: four, dtype: int64

In [158]: s.loc[:, 'X', :] = s2

In [159]: s
Out[159]:
one  two  three
a    X    u         3
          v        -3
b    Y    u         4
a    Z    u        20
Name: four, dtype: int64
```

Probably worth searching for similar issues in https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues and adding it as a new one if it's not already there.

One other option in the meantime is to use `.unstack()` to reshape your data to do the assignment:

```
In [181]: s = s.unstack('two')

In [182]: s['X'].loc[s2.index] = s2

In [183]: s.stack().swaplevel(1,2).sort_index()
Out[183]:
one  two  three
a    X    u         3.0
          v        -3.0
     Z    u        20.0
b    Y    u         4.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks these workarounds look good. Will file a bug later if I can't find a duplicate.

Comment: Also, my actual index has a lot more values so I didn't want to write out the product. I found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744068/prepend-a-level-to-a-pandas-multiindex) that gave me a good way to add the level to the index of `s2`:
`s2 = pd.concat({'X': s2}, names=['two']).swaplevel(0, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @randy answer you can convert `s2` to list, so you won't have to care about indexes matching (but then it won't be like a `join` but just an assignment preserving order on both sides):

```py
>>> s.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'X', :]]=s2.to_list()
>>> s
one  two  three
a    X    u         3.0
          v        -3.0
b    Y    u         4.0
a    Z    u        20.0
Name: four, dtype: float64
```