# Split a bottom level column tuple into another level

Tags: python, dataframe

My current dataframe has two levels. I'm looking to add a third by splitting tuples, which are the names of the columns. See example:

Original DF:

```
Category
(A,Cat)    (B,Dog)    (B,Bird)   (B,Frog)   (HH,Lion)   (HH,Tiger)

  48          28         585        4          233         44
  11          434         23        854         32         10
```

Desired DF: "Category" is top level. Letter (A,B,HH) is the second level. Then the animal is the bottom level of the dataframe

```
Category
   A           B          B          B          HH         HH 
  Cat         Dog        Bird      Frog       Lion      Tiger

  48          28         585        4          233         44
  11          434         23        854         32         10
```

I don't have much experience with working with Multi-index columns in dataframes. Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First starting with what you have (would've been nice if you had provided this code yourself):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[48, 28, 585, 4, 233, 44], [11, 434, 23, 854, 32, 10]],
    columns=[("A", "Cat"), ("B", "Dog"), ("B", "Bird"), ("B", "Frog"), ("HH", "Lion"), ("HH", "Tiger")],
)

df
```

```
   (A, Cat)  (B, Dog)  (B, Bird)  (B, Frog)  (HH, Lion)  (HH, Tiger)
0        48        28        585          4         233           44
1        11       434         23        854          32           1
```

Now break down the tuples into multi-level columns and then prepend another level:

```py
# Create multi-index from existing column tuples
# https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)

# Add another level for the 'Category'
# From https://stackoverflow.com/a/42094658/1256347
pd.concat([df], keys=['Category'], axis=1)
```

```
  Category                          
         A    B             HH      
       Cat  Dog Bird Frog Lion Tiger
0       48   28  585    4  233    44
1       11  434   23  854   32    10
```